# Syntax highlighting: Geany doesn't 'see' imported structs, methods.

Tags: gtk, syntax-highlighting, geany

So I'm doing some programming at home, and I'm using the GTK+2.0 library.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>

GtkWidget *window;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window); 
    gtk_main();         
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and runs fine.

The problem I'm having is that geany doesn't seem to 'know' that it's using the gtk library, or what methods and structs are in it.

So for example that GtkWidget struct isn't highlighted, it's just plaintext. It doesn't offer the dropdown of methods, when I start writing 'gtk_window...'.

What do?

Comment: You might have better luck asking on Super User, since this question is about configuring your editor, not programming.

Comment: I agree with @ptomato - not the right venue. However you probably need to tell the editor about the symbols using "tags" files: http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#default-global-tags-files

Comment: There's a bunch of pre-made tag files on the wiki (including GTK+): http://wiki.geany.org/tags/start

Answer (score 1):

Open the header file in Geany. It will then parse the contents and highlight structs, etc, in other open files.